# Implementing Tree in Perl - Children cut off

Tags: perl, data-structures, tree

I'm to learn Perl for a job interview over weekend. In order to get a deeper understanding I'm trying to implement a tree class.

```
#use strict;
#use warnings;

package Tree;

sub new {
    my $class   = shift @_;
    my $content = shift @_;
    my @array   = shift @_;
    return bless { "content" => $content, "array" => @array }, $class;
}

sub num_children {
    my $self = shift @_;
    my @array = $self->{"array"};
    return scalar @array;
}

return 1;
```

To test the (faulty) tree class I have implemented the following test script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require Tree;

my $t = Tree->new("#", undef);
my $tt = Tree->new("*", undef);
my $tttt = Tree->new("-", undef);
my $ttttt = Tree->new(".", undef);

my @list = ();
push @list, $tt;
push @list, $t;
push @list, $tttt;
push @list, $ttttt;


my $ttt = Tree->new("+", @list);

print $ttt->num_children();
```

Unfortunately the output is `1` instead of my expection of `4`. I assume the array is somehow cut off or unvoluntarily converted to a scalar. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that you can't pass arrays as a single value—you have to pass a reference instead.

Also, you should *never* comment out `use strict` and `use warnings`. They are valuable debugging tools, and if you are getting error messages with them enabled you should fix the errors that they are flagging instead.

Here's a working `Tree.pm`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Tree;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my ($content, $array) = @_;
    return bless { content => $content, array => $array }, $class;
}

sub num_children {
    my $self = shift;
    my $array = $self->{array};
    return scalar @$array;
}

1;
```

and the calling program `tree_test.pl`. Note that you should `use` rather than `require` a module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tree;

my @list = map { Tree->new($_) } ('#', '*', '-', '.');

my $ttt = Tree->new('+', \@list);

print $ttt->num_children, "\n";
```

**output**

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

`shift` only removes one element from an array. Populate `@array` without it:

```
 my @array = @_;
```

But, you can't store an array in a hash directly, you have to use a reference:

```
return bless { content => $content,
               array   => \@array,
             }, $class;
```

which you then have to dereference:

```
my @array = @{ $self->{array} };
return scalar @array
```